# Is there a way to check which VNC clients are running and listening for connections?

Tags: vnc

I am using VNC to manage around 70 different PC's running Windows 10.

Is there a way I can check to see if each client has it's VNC service running and listening for connections without having to manually connect and check to each one?

I'm hoping to gain enough information to create a system that will check the clients every morning and inform me of clients who don't have an active VNC service running and listening for connections.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any tool which can determine if a port is open or not will work. VNC uses 5900 as the default port.

One possible solution using Powershell is:

`Test-NetConnection <host> -Port 5900`

which gives the following output for me on a machine running TightVNC server:

```
ComputerName     : zebedee
RemoteAddress    : 192.168.0.6
RemotePort       : 5900
InterfaceAlias   : WiFi
SourceAddress    : 192.168.0.121
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

You can reduce this to just `True` or `False` by appending `-InformationLevel Quiet`.

You should be able to roll a batch file which connects to a range of IP addresses, checks the output of `Test-NetConnection` and reports the machines which don't have VNC running.